# VS2015 Load testing - How can a request take longer than the max time generated by load test analysis results?

Tags: performance, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, performance-testing, load-testing

In my test mix if my simulated users are all making the same exact request over and over, how is possible for me in the detailed tab to see that a individual request had a longer duration than the max page response time shown by the load test analysis?

[image: Duration was 2.428s]

[image: Max response time was 0.61s]

Answer (score 0):

The two values are not comparable.

The details tabs does not show page times, it shows test durations. A test can contain several requests. Each request can cause several pages (ie dependant requests) to be loaded. Each request can have think times.